# How To Fill A Javascript Form Using Selenium In Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to fill out a form with Selenium. I originally used requests but was told that requests does not handle Javascript form filling in this context. Essentially what my issue is finding the actual input id: of the form itself so I can insert that data and submit it (code below) I am not familiar with Selenium but have managed to read documentation and figure out a few things along the way. For this i'm going to use hotwire.com So I need to find the form input id: if you got to hotwire.com you will see "Destination", "check-in" , "check-out" along with number of guests an finally the big red " Find A Hotel" button. So what is Destination ID? what is Check-in ID what is Check-out ID ? this is the only thing stumping me at this point along with how to actually use these the process. How do you guys find the correct input id thats appropriate when filling out a form using a web inspector? I have spent hours trying to find the correct tags and still have no luck as I watch the browser open, load page, and fill no data in.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException



hotwireF = "https://www.hotwire.com"

# Use Safari to open URL
driver = webdriver.Safari()
# go to URL
driver.get(hotwireF)





search_form = driver.find_element_by_id("destination")
search_form.send_keys("POP")
```

Comment: You can try using  'JavascriptExcutor' in selenium

Comment: thanks for the response I actually got it now essentially in Python i just used the web inspector and got the " XPath" copied then plugged into my code. It worked quite well actually, having since done that I switched to Java to accommodate a larger scale project with more emphasis on OOP/OOD and clarity as I find Python great for smaller scripts but gets messy fast compared to cumbersome Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException



hotwireF = "https://www.hotwire.com/hotels/results/"

# data to be changed accordingly...
data = {"destination"   :   "London",
        "startDate"     :   "09-08-2017",
        "endDate"       :   "09-09-2017",
        "No. rooms"     :   "1",
        "No. Adults"    :   "2",
        "No. Children"  :   "1"}

# Use Safari to open URL
driver = webdriver.Safari()
# go to URL
driver.get(hotwireF + "".join([data[i]+"/" for i in data]))
```